# overridePendingTransition from a service giving error

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to start an intent from a service using **overridePendingTransition** it looks like this

```
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, PopUpMainActivity.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(dialogIntent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
```

But it showing error.

```
The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined for the type MyServiceForPopUp
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can only call `overridePendingTransition` from activity.

More information here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-porting/M42HBc90hz4/HXz7aY1KqlYJ